# Continuous map on a dense subset which is not closed

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, closed-map

I'm trying to prove that if $p:X\to Y$ is continuous, $D$ is a dense proper subset of $X$ and $p^{-1}(y)\cap D$ is compact for every $y\in Y$, then the restriction $\left.p\right|_D$ is not closed.

I guess that the idea is to assume that $\left.p\right|_D$ is closed and arrive to a contradiction, but all my attempts ends with no success and in the very most I never found where to use the compactness condition.

I'll appreciate any help.

**EDIT:** This is exercise 9 page 254 of Dugundji's *Topology*, concerning compactness and perfect maps.

Comment: Idea: if the restriction were closed it would be a perfect map from $D$ to $p[D]$. What do you know about dense subsets and perfect maps?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I realized of that, but couldn't conclude anything because I don't have too much information about this two conditions. In fact the book only tell us properties that are preserved under perfect maps.

Comment: If $p: D  \to p[D] $ is perfect, $p[X\setminus D] = Y\setminus p[D]$ (remainders to remainders theorem). Maybe this helps. I don't see a direct contradiction yet, unless $p$ is assumed to be onto $Y$.

Comment: Any hidden Hausdorff assumptions here? (e.g. compact includes Hausdorff or not i Dugundji's text?)

Comment: Yes, the space is assumed to be Hausdorff!

Comment: Which space is Hausdorff, X or Y or both?

Comment: I asked Henno's question. Compactness in Dugundji's book is defined over Hausdorff spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is Hausdorff then the positive answer to your question follows from Lemma 3.7.4 from [Eng]. Recall that a continuous map $f:X\to Y$ is *perfect* if $X$ is a Hausdorff space, $f$ is a closed map and all fibers $f^{-1}(y)$ are compact subsets of $X$.

[image]

[image]

*References*

[Eng] Ryszard Engelking, *General Topology*, 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.